# Can you view and edit rails code locally?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is it possible to view the code for Rails locally?

With gems, you can find the local source code in your gem folder and add breakpoints, comments, and make changes.

Is that possible with Rails? When I go to `.rvm/gems/ruby-3.2.0/gems/rails-7.0.4` I can only see a readme. `which rails` points me to `.rvm/gems/ruby-3.2.0/bin` which only contains executables.

Comment: You're just doing it wrong. `which` is used to find the path to an executable. If you want to see where a gem is located you run `gem which rails`. And no you don't need to clone the gem from github.

Comment: one gem at a time `bundle show activerecord` or search `bundle show "^(active|action|railt)"` or `bundle show --paths | ag "7.0.4"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can. The issue that you currently face is the fact that the `rails` gem is nothing more then a collection of other gems. The `rails` gem doesn't include any code.

This is the [`rails.gemspec`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v7.0.4/rails.gemspec):

```rb
# ...

Gem::Specification.new do |s|

  # ...

  s.files = ["README.md"]

  # ...

  s.add_dependency "activesupport", version
  s.add_dependency "actionpack",    version
  s.add_dependency "actionview",    version
  s.add_dependency "activemodel",   version
  s.add_dependency "activerecord",  version
  s.add_dependency "actionmailer",  version
  s.add_dependency "activejob",     version
  s.add_dependency "actioncable",   version
  s.add_dependency "activestorage", version
  s.add_dependency "actionmailbox", version
  s.add_dependency "actiontext",    version
  s.add_dependency "railties",      version

  s.add_dependency "bundler", ">= 1.15.0"
end
```

Like you can see the only file this gem provides is `README.md`. Other than that it includes a bunch of dependencies, which together form the `rails` gem.

If you want to view code locally you first have to figure what you're trying to view. Then go to the relevant gem instead of going to `rails`. For example, if you want to view the source for some of the Ruby core extensions that Rails provides. You'll probably have to search in `activesupport`.

In your scenario the source would then be located in:

```
~/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.2.0/gems/activesupport-7.0.4/...
```

Alternatively your IDE might support <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + Click, which takes you directly to the relevant source. I mostly use RubyMine which supports this feature.

If you only want to view the source, you could also visit the Ruby on Rails API documentation instead. https://api.rubyonrails.org/v7.0.4

Answer (score 1):

Clone Rails from github.

Check-out the version of rails that matches the version you have installed.

For version 7.0.4, that's `git co 8015c2c`

In your gemfile, point the rails gem to this local version

`gem "rails", path: "[path]/rails"`

Then run bundle.